# Determining codesigning identities from the command line?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, codesign

I'm trying to set up an automated way to sign my iOS apps. Before using codesign, is there a way to programmatically determine from the command line what my valid signing identities are?

For example, for the command

```
codesign -v --sign "iPhone Distribution: Joe Developer" /path/to/app
```

How could I figure out that "iPhone Distribution: Joe Developer" is a valid identity?  How would I figure other valid identities?

I'd prefer a way to do this from within a command line, but from within cocoa would work as well.

Answer (score 155):

To get a list of signing identities, I found the perfect answer [in this objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/):

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

It gives output like:

```
1) 4E8D512C8480FAC679947D6E50190AE9BAB3E825 "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Developer Name (DUCNFCN445)"
2) 8B0EBBAE7E7230BB6AF5D69CA09B769663BC844D "Mac Developer: Developer Name (DUCNFCN445)"
3) 4E8D512C8480AAC67995D69CA09B769663BC844D "iPhone Developer: App Developer (DUCNFCN445)"
4) 65E24CDAF5B3E1E1480818CA4656210871214337 "Developer ID Application: App Developer (DUCNFCN445)"
   4 valid identities found
```

Comment: If you created a self signed certificate and it does not show up in the list, here's what you need to do: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/350686/15832978/e88d362a-2c24-11e6-98ee-b70e86ab36a7.png