# What is the value of codesigning_identity in build_app of fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I was trying to use this fastlane [script](https://github.com/vector-im/element-ios/blob/develop/fastlane/Fastfile). The script is being failed at the end as its picking up the wrong codesigning_identity [image]. Its being used in build_app function line number 148. I know I can assign the right value with the export command. But I just don't know where can I get the value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/31626407/3538092, you can get it with:

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

The part that you'll use will be something like "iPhone Developer: App Developer (XXXXXXXXXX)".